# What is the best way in PHP or JS to expand shortened URLs like Bitly, Tinyurl to find the original URL?

Tags: php, javascript, bit.ly, url-shortener

I am using the Twitter and Facewbook API to pull posts that potentially contain shortened URLs using bit.ly or TinyURL like services. I need to do a real-time expansion to get the original URL then pull content from that URL into my app.

Comment: You should also keep in mind that the source url can be shortened 100 times with different shorteners pointed to each other ;-)))

Comment: @zerkms Bullshit. APIs would be useless if you couldn't use them.

Comment: @ceejayoz: huh? short url can point to **any** site, that does not provide any API and that contains copyrighted content. OP wants to grab that contents.

Comment: Still bullshit. Your argument would ban the Google cache, Archive.org, and countless other web services. You don't even know what he's doing with the app - it's possible he's doing some sort of analysis on it instead of displaying directly to the user.

Comment: @ceejayoz: it doesn't matter what kind of app he is writing - before you use copyrighted information **in any way** (either analytics or displaying) you should ask. You can disable indexing by search engines with robots.txt, but you cannot do the same against such grabbers.

Comment: @beactive: You should design your application to respect robots.txt.

Comment: @zerkms First, you're making some very sweeping legal generalizations that don't apply worldwide. Second, Google doesn't seem to allow you to exclude caching while remaining in their normal index via robots.txt, you need a meta tag of their own design. Third, there are plenty of fair use situations in which this'd be perfectly legal in the US. Hell, your standard even bans web browsers - they don't ask permission and they don't use robots.txt.

Comment: @ceejayoz: websites are built to be used by people, if other is not allowed explicitly. You are permitted to open any page in browser, but you are not permitted to copy-paste it.

Comment: @zerkms When you visit a webpage, your browser downloads it to display it. This is no different from a GUI-less client. If you would then publish the data without attribution and permission, you'd be in trouble.

Comment: @zerkms and Arda Xi, Facebook already does exactly what I assume the OP is intending to do - pulls resources to provide a thumbnailed link to an article rather than a normal link. He didn't say he was going to publish it without attribution, and it's not illegal unless he claims the content is his or the user is led to assume that.

Answer (score 12):

You can use CURL to expand a short URL.

Try this:

```
    function traceUrl($url, $hops = 0)
    {
        if ($hops == MAX_URL_HOPS)
        {
            throw new Exception('TOO_MANY_HOPS');
        }

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $r = curl_exec($ch);

        if (preg_match('/Location: (?P<url>.*)/i', $r, $match))
        {
            return traceUrl($match['url'], $hops + 1);
        }

        return rtrim($url);
    }
```

You can use this function as so `traceUrl('http://bit.ly/example')`. This function is recursive in the sense that it will even find short urls that are shortened (if it ever happens). Make sure you set the `MAX_URL_HOPS` constant. I use `define('MAX_URL_HOPS', 5);`.

- Christian

Comment: I had a beer once that made me throw that exception :P

Answer (score 7):

You can just use PHP and CURL to connect to the URL and get back the `Location` parameter:

Here is what comes back -

```
> $ curl -I http://bit.ly/2V6CFi
> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Server:
> nginx/0.7.67 Date: Tue, 21 Dec 2010
> 01:58:47 GMT Content-Type: text/html;
> charset=utf-8 Connection: keep-alive
> Set-Cookie:
> _bit=4d1009d7-00298-02f7f-c6ac8fa8;domain=.bit.ly;expires=Sat
> Jun 18 21:58:47 2011;path=/; HttpOnly
> Cache-control: private; max-age=90
> Location: http://www.google.com/
> MIME-Version: 1.0

Content-Length: 284
```

So you can look for the Location parameter in the header to see where the page page actually goes.

Comment: I would also add `-X HEAD` if all OP needs on this step is just a "long" url.

Comment: @zerkms I used -I instead, which basically does the same thing

Answer (score 2):

With nodejs you can use the module **[request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)**.

```
var request = require('request');
var shortUrl = 'the url that is shortened'
request({method: 'HEAD', url: shortUrl, followAllRedirects: true}, 
  function(err, response, body){
     console.log(response.request.href);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a php library that does just that, it can be useful.
Check it out: https://launchpad.net/longurl